# Alternatives to pyipc lib for IPC with python

Tags: python, ipc

I use for an old project pyipc a Python binings to System V interprocess communication mechanisms: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyipc/

that work well, I use it like this:

```
from ipc import Semaphore, MessageQueue
...
```

But it seems not maintain any more.

What is the more modern way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is `POSIX IPC` and `SysV IPC`:

[POSIX IPC](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/posix_ipc) provides Python access to POSIX IPC primitives, it is a little easier to use than [SysV IPC](http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/), but not all operating systems support it completely.

Works under Python 2.7 and 3.x

Answer (score 0):

check the multiprocessing module in the standard library

https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html